# Mathematical Mystery 4

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge

> Known by 2 names, argued by ways
>   One of them sounds irregular, sometimes that pays
>   My legs are like a human's, usually alike
>   This is easy, known by a child's psyche

**Name the mathematical concept**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a

> Trapezoid / Trapezium

Since

> People debate over its name and it has two equal legs.

Comment: Correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Integral?

Reasoning:

> Integrals can be definite or they can be indefinite (2 names). 'Indefinite' also means uncertain, which suggests irregularity. I'm guessing that the 'pays' part of line 2 is there for rhyming purposes. Integrals can be approximated by the sum of the area of minute rectangles of the same width (the 'legs' are the same size). Not sure if children know how to do integrals, however, but knowledge of integrals is a prerequisite for a lot of math, physics...ect, so maybe the last line just means that integrals are elementary compared to a lot of stuff that requires knowledge about them?

Comment: It isn't an integral

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A star/asterisk *

Known by 2 names, argued by ways

> Asterisk/star

One of them sounds irregular, sometimes that pays

> Maybe asterisk sounds irregular?

My legs are like a human's, usually alike

> The points of an asterisk are usually drawn the same way and same length

This is easy, known by a child's psyche

> A child knows it as a star, but mathematicians use it for many purposes like multiplication, A* search, convolution etc

Answer (score 1):

It could be(partial one)

> Pi

As,

Known by 2 names, argued by ways

> It (the sounding word)is known by *pi* and it's homophone *pie*

One of them sounds irregular, sometimes that pays

> Not sure on this part...

My legs are like a human's, usually alike

> It is obvious, when represented with two vertical lines connected by a horizontal line at the top.

This is easy, known by a child's psyche

> Child's psyche could be towards a sweet, usually( though an assumption!) - for which a possibility is *pie*

Name the mathematical concept

> It is pi.